# Map documents to different entities

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a problem with designing my database.

I have a table which contains documents with the following table-structure:

```
[Documents]
Id [int] 
FileName [varchar]
FileFormat [varchar]
FileContent [image]
```

In my program: each document can be standalone (without any relationship to an entity) or with an relation to an object either of type Customer or Employee (some more are probably coming soon)

Each entity has an Id in the database. For example the Employee-Table looks like:

```
[Employee]
Id [int]
Fk_NameId [int]
Fk_AddressId [int]
Fk_ContactId [int]
```

My idea is to create a table for the connection of an entity and an document. I thought about something like:

```
[DocumentConnection]
DocumentId [int]
EntityId [int]
Entity [varchar]
```

The entity-column in the DocumentConnection-Table contains the table-name of the relation.

In the example of an entity of type Employee this column would contain "Employee".
In my application then I build the select-statement for the document by reading the entity-string from the database.

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't DocumentConnection also need an EmployeeID/CustomerID field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be a much better design to have an EmployeeDocument table, CustomerDocument table, etc.

That will allow you to use foreign keys to the entity tables, which would not be possible in your proposed design.  In your design, you would be able to put anything in the entity and entityId columns and it would not be enforceable via foreign key relationship that it actually relates to an existing entity.

The only reason I can see for using your DocumentConnection table would be if your application needed to dynamically create new types of relationships.  I assume that isn't the case since you said each type of entity will have its own table.

Comment: Yes, each type of entity will have it's own table. But if I move a document from an employee to a customer than I'll have to delete it from the employee-table and add new to the customer table, right?

Comment: @Tomtom, well yes. I suppose that's slightly more work than updating two fields in your DocumentConnection table.  IMO, that's a small price to pay for enabling the database to enforce referential integrity.